# how to Trim URL to home page in java

Tags: java, url

I am unable to trim a long URL upto homepage or index page.

Ex:

```
http://www.simplybestcoupons.co.uk/Coupons/elance.com/
```

Result:

```
http://www.simplybestcoupons.co.uk
```

Comment: You could do it with Regular Expressions, Subtrings + IndexOf or with the URL-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.simplybestcoupons.co.uk/Coupons/elance.com/");
System.out.println(url.getProtocol()+"://"+url.getHost());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String example = "http://www.simplybestcoupons.co.uk/Coupons/elance.com/";
example = example.replaceAll("com/.*", "");
```

This will replace all chars after com/